# Inequalities of singular values

Tags: linear-algebra

[image: I'm trying to solve this problem from horn and johnson]

My attempt: Let $A=U\Sigma V^*$ be the singular value decomposition of $A$ where $U$ and $V$ are unitary. Now let $\hat{A}=\begin{bmatrix}0 &A \\A^*& 0\\\end{bmatrix}$ and $\hat{\Sigma}=\begin{bmatrix}0&\Sigma\\\Sigma^*&0\\\end{bmatrix}$. From here what I'm trying to do is relate the eigenvalues of $\hat{A}$ to the eigenvalues of $\hat{\Sigma}$, but I can't see any relation. Is my approach right or I'm missing something? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: How are the singular values ordered? I suspect that you mean $\sigma_1(A) \geq \cdots \geq \sigma_n(A)$; either way, please clarify this explicitly.

Comment: Also, what is $q$? I suspect that you mean $q = \min\{m,n\}$.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach a correct approach to prove the first inequality. Note that $\hat A$ is unitarily similar to $\hat\Sigma$, and you can show that the non-zero eigenvalues of $\hat \Sigma$ are equal to the non-zero eigenvalues of $\Sigma$, which are in turn the singular values of $\hat A$. From there, applying [Weyl's inequalities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weyl%27s_inequality#Weyl%27s_inequality_about_perturbation) to $\hat A, \hat B, \hat A + \hat B$ produces the desired result.

---

*The below is my work in progress for the second part.*

The second result is tricky to prove. One approach is as follows. First of all, we note that if either $A$ or $B$ have rank less than $i+j-1$, then the same holds for $AB^*$, which means that
$$
\sigma_{(i-1) + j}(AB^*) =  0,
$$
so that the inequality trivially holds

Now, suppose that $A$ and $B$ both have rank at least $i + j - 1$. We use the following notation:

- $u_j,\dots,u_q$ denote the left singular vectors of $B$ corresponding to $\sigma_j(B),\dots,\sigma_q(B)$.
- $U_1 = \operatorname{span}(\{u_j,\dots,u_q\}) \subset \Bbb C^m$
- $v_i \dots,v_q$ denote the right singular vectors of $A$ corresponding to $\sigma_i(A),\dots,\sigma_q(A)$
- $V_2 = \operatorname{span}(\{v_i,\dots,v_q\}) \subset \Bbb C^n$
- $U_2 = B^{-*}(V_2) \subset\Bbb C^m$.

If $\Pi_2$ denotes the projection onto $V_2^\perp = \operatorname{im}(A)$, then $U_2 = \ker(\Pi_2 \circ B^*)$, which has dimension at least $\min\{\operatorname{rank}(A),\dim \ker(B^*)\}$.

Let $r = \operatorname{rank}(B)$.

Let $v_1,\dots,v_j \in \Bbb C^m$ denote the leading left singular vectors of $B$, and let $V = \operatorname{span}(\{v_1,\dots,v_j\})$. For all vectors $x \in V$, it holds that $\|B^*x\| \geq \sigma_j(B)\|x\|$. Similarly, let $u_i,\dots,u_q$ denote the trailing right singular vectors of $A$ and take $U = \operatorname{span}(\{u_i,\dots,u_q\})$.

to use [the min max theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-max_theorem) for singular values. Note that
$$
\sigma_{i+j-1}(AB^*) = \max_{\dim(U) = i+j} \min\{\|AB^*x\| :x \in U, \|x\| = 1\}
$$